# Android: data is not uploading to Azure table problem using .apk file version

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, azure-storage

I uploaded data to `Azure` table storage

Here is my `AzureEntity` code

```
public class AzureEntity extends TableServiceEntity {

private String foodName;

    public AzureEntity(String dateTime) {
        this.partitionKey = "test";
        this.rowKey = dateTime;
    }

    public String getFoodName() {
        return foodName;
    }

    public void setFoodName(String foodName) {
        this.foodName = foodName;
    }
```

my `AddAzureEntityTask` code is

```
public class AddAzureEntityTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
            + "AccountName=xxx"
            + "AccountKey=xxx"
            + "EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

    private static CloudTableClient tableClient;
    private static CloudTable table;
    private final static String tableName = "test";
    private AzureEntity azureEntity;

    public AddAzureEntityTask(AzureEntity entity) {
        azureEntity = entity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount
                    .parse(storageConnectionString);
            tableClient = account.createCloudTableClient();
            table = tableClient.getTableReference(tableName);
            table.createIfNotExists();
            this.BasicInsertEntity();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void BasicInsertEntity() throws StorageException{
        TableOperation insertEntity = TableOperation.insert(azureEntity);
        table.execute(insertEntity);

    }
}
```

and I added data to azure using

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);

    AzureEntity azureEntity = new AzureEntity(sdf.format(realm.getDateTime()));
    azureEntity.setFoodName(realm.getFoodName());
    new AddAzureEntityTask(azureEntity).execute();
```

It worked normally when I run app via Android Studio [data was uploaded to Azure correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO6Ka.png) but when I installed my app by generated `apk` file [foodName data is sent null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jE38.png)

I want to know what's going on and How to fix this problem?

Comment: Try to write [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the sample code and post in in the question (in case the link expires). Also post the output of your program as the code, not as the images.